# Password does not work anymore

Tags: login, password

Today I took a look at the **/etc/shadow** file with the password-hashes **without changing** it **but saving** it again. After again starting my PC with **Linux Mint 19.4** I entered my password and that also worked. But if I **enter my Password after standby-mode** I get displayed that it **is wrong** even though i definitly entered it right.

I also tried to change my password in the graphical account settings which resulted in the same error.

When changing it with "sudo passwd" i can change it successfully but I still cannot login after standby-mode.

Does anyone know what the reason for this could be and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I used nano editor and

`ls -l /etc/shadow` shows that noone has any rights (--------- 1 root shadow ...)

Comment: Result of `ls -l /etc/shadow` please. And tell us which editor you used. Put your reply into your question - as if you'd written it with this information from the start. (You may need to use a rescue boot disk if you can't log in.)

Comment: my shadow has `-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1.6K Aug  7 15:38 /etc/shadow`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor CentOS 7 has permissions 000. Debian Stretch has 640. I might have to dig out a copy of Mint 19.

Comment: @user the solution should go in an Answer box, not the title. Thank you!